# Kingsoft office application mime type

Tags: javascript

How can I add the Kingsoft office application mime type?

Below is my script where I have added the MIME type however not able find Kingsoft office applications

```
mimeTypes: "image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/msword",
```

Answer (score 0):

i think following mime type will help

> Mime type: application/vnd.ms-works, application/x-msworks-wp, zz-application/zz-winassoc-wps, text/plain

Comment: I able to view the file but not able to upload now, getting error "Selected file[User.xlsx]is not supported to upload  "

Comment: Yes, only when i am uploading Kingsoft xlsx